# Java - Pass double as arguments without giving actual value

Tags: java, arrays, argument-passing

Got an error at :        Movie m = new Movie(id, name, cost);

"cannot find symbol - var cost"

cost is set only when user insert input and cannot put actual value e.g.200.00

What should I put as argument?

Also, Session can only be created if user enters correct movie ID.

How do I match compare input(int) to an array?

Any help will be appreciated. Explanation is also important for me

Movie Class:

```
private void addMovie()
    
    {
        System.out.println("Setup a Movie");
        int id = movies.setId();
        String name = In.readString("Enter Movie Name: ");
        double cost = In.readDouble("Enter Movie Cost:" );

        Movie movie = new Movie(id, name, cost);
        movies.add(movie);
        
        menu();
    }
```

Session Class:

```
private void addSession()
{   
    System.out.println("Add a Session");
    int id = sessions.setId();        
    String name = In.readString("Enter Session Name: ");
    int movieId = In.readInt("Enter Movie id:" );
    **//match input with id array**
    int theatreId = In.readInt("Enter Theatre id:" );
    **//match input with theatre id array**
    String sessionTime = In.readString("Enter Session Time - 0 for 9am, 1 for 12noon, 2 for 3pm or 3 for 6pm: ");
    double GoldSeatsPrices = In.readDouble("Enter Prices fro Gold Class Seats:");
    double ReguSeatsPrices = In.readDouble("Enter Prices for Regular Seats:");
    Movie m = new Movie(id, name, cost);
    Session session = new Session(id, name, m);
    sessions.add(session);
    
    menu();
}
```

Movie Class:

```
    public class Movie extends Record
{   
    private double cost;
    public Movie(int id, String name, double cost)
    {
        super(id, name);
        this.cost = cost;  
    }
    public double getCost()
    {
        return cost;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Movie: "+ super.toString() + " cost: $"+ cost;
    }
}
```

Records Class: (super.):

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 * class Records - complete
 */
public class Records
{
    protected LinkedList<Record> records = new LinkedList<Record>();
    protected int id = 0;
    protected Record find(int id)
    {   
        for(Record record: records)
        {  
            if (record.matches(id))
                return record;  
        }
        return null;    
    }  
    protected void add(Record record)
    {
        records.add(record);
    }
    public int size()
    {
        return records.size();
    }
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println(toString());
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        String str = "";
        for(Record record : records)
            str += record.toString() + "\n";
        return str;
    }
}
```

Record:

```
/**
 * class Record - complete
 */
public class Record 
{
    protected int id;
    protected String name;

    public Record(int id, String name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public boolean matches(int id)
    {
       return this.id == id;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return id + " " + name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe make a separate constructor that accepts two arguements

Comment: Does it make sense for a Movie to exist without a cost? If not, why not create a class called "UnpricedMovie" or something that has a method that converts it to a "Movie" which takes a "cost" as a parameter?

Comment: Please mark your question as answered, if a solution suits your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To the first question: There is no variable `cost` within `addSession()`. If you have not defined an attribute `cost` within Session then this is the problem.

To the second question: I am not quite sure that I understand your problem correctly. You have an `int[] values` and want to know, whether a given int `x` is within that array? If so, you can achieve this with this code snippet:

```
for (int value : values) {
    if (value == x) {
        // Put code, that should be executed when the value is found, here
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way rather than declare an cost attribute?

Comment: Define a constructor for `Movie`, which does not requires that parameter (see @Bret's comment)

Comment: Sessions is extends Records which has linkedList call <Record>.

for (int record : records)
{   if (record ==x)  } ........

What is the 'x'  here???

Comment: the `x` is the movie-id in question, i.e. the value you got from the user.

Comment: for (int id : ????) {  if  (id == movieId) { } }
I tried to put Movies, movies as 'values' but doesn't work

Comment: Of course it does not. You asked me about `int[]` and now you are talking about a `LinkedList<Record>`. Please specify your question more precisely next time. You may want to override `equals(Object o)` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you place the Super class Record also in your question?
Probably, you need to check the super constructor, which is differing from your sub class constructor.

Comment: @NewToJava, I tried your code as below and I was able to go without any issues   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a movie name");
  String name = in.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Enter movie cost");
  double cost = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
  Movie movie1 = new Movie(100, name, cost);
  System.out.println(movie1.toString());

Comment: Can I have your email if possible? there are other classes in the package and I really need help with it. Thanks

Comment: Error when compile session class:         Movie m = new Movie(id, name, cost);            not in movie class